# Runtime overwriting List elements when adding new object

Tags: java, arraylist, pass-by-reference

I have task implementing `Runnable`, which need to populate `ArrayList` with custom classes extending `TimerTask`.

My code:

```
public class ClusterSessionTask implements Runnable {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    CheckTask checkTask = null;
    Map<String, String> keyspaces = getKeyspaces(cluster_name);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> key_to_colfam : keyspaces.entrySet()) {
      String k = key_to_colfam.getKey();
      String c = key_to_colfam.getValue();
      checkTask = new CheckTask(k, c, session);
      tasks.add(checkTask);
    }
  }
}
```

You can see I am initialising new `CheckTask` every iteration in the for loop, but I am still getting the previous elements in the list being overwritten.

See this debug info:

on the 1st iteration you can see the task `a:b`
[image: first]

But on the second one `a:b` is being overwritten by the new task `c:d`:
[image]

`CheckTask` is a class extending `TimerTask`:

```
class CheckTask extends TimerTask {
  private static int i = 0;
  private static String keyspace;
  private static String colfam;
  private static CqlSession session;

  CheckTask(String k, String c, CqlSession s) {
    keyspace = k;
    colfam = c;
    session = s;
  }

  public void run() {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return keyspace + ":" + colfam;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? it is somehow passing the object by reference and the `new` commend being ignored?

Thanks

Comment: What is a CheckTask?

Comment: Sorry - Editing with the relevant info.

Comment: Your variables are static...

Comment: I agree with assylias  the root cause is that your varaibles are static, also make sure to use thread-safe Array list (Collections.synchronizedList() or CopyOnWriteArrayList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the static keyword for  keyspace,colfam,session in the constructor.

Even if you create 2 instances , they would share same value

Comment: Damn, how did I missed that.. Thanks so much!!